# java types which is not type primitive

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

I'm familiar with the java primitive types which is described in the following link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html
but my question is to which type the following types is related

```
BigDecimal ,
java.util.Date
String 

....
```

where can i found doc that describe the type which are not primitive and are not related to list hashMap etc
I talking about types that can be defined as class members.

Answer (score 2):

you can find those information in java api. for example, `BigDecimal`:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Any type can be defined as type of a class member.

Comment: but to which type is related ?what about fields like java.util.Date there is similar types ?.i mean  "simple fields" not referance ,list etc.

Comment: @JohnJerrby what do you mean "related" ? e.g. util.Date, if you open the source codes of this class, you will see it has int, long....BaseCalendar fields. Do you mean those types are related?

Comment: @JohnJerrby then you need to go into the source codes of those types.

Answer (score 1):

> which type the following types is related

If understand this as the "relationship" between `int` and `Integer` for example, then the classes you mentioned do not have any "related" primitive type.

But as mentioned previously, any class can be a class member.

A list of the correspondence among primitive types and their wrapper classes can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)

```
Primitive type  Wrapper class

boolean         Boolean
byte            Byte
char            Character
float           Float
int             Integer
long            Long
short           Short
```